# Create query to compare Feature state in current vs previous iteration

Tags: azure-devops

I need to find a way to create a chart query to compare how many features were New, Active, etc. on previous iteration and how they are now.

I've created a query and chart with the count of features grouped by state and iteration path, but I couldn't find a way to get how things were in a previous iteration.

Is it possible on Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Iteration Path` value as `@CurrentIteration +/- n` in query.

For example:

@CurrentIteration: Current Iteration Path

@CurrentIteration -1 : Previous iteration path.

[image: Filters]

The query result will return the work items in **Current Iteration Path** and **Previos Iteration Path**.

Then you could create a chart for the query (sort by Iteration path and state).

[image: Chart]

Here is the doc about [Query settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#sliding-window-of-team-iterations-query).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this approach will return items currently set to current or previous iteration only. Suppose I have a feature A that in previous iteration were `Active` and in current iteration it is `Closed`, I need to have a chart for the previous iteration counting this feature A as `Active` and another chart for current iteration counting it as `Closed`.

Comment: As far as I know,  the query result could only show the work item current state. It seems that azure devops doesn't support to show the previous state in query result. So your requirement couldn't be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

What is the need for a team for this?  Does the graphic CFD not meet this need?

There are other ways like:

- Query using the field: History
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser
- Historical queries (ASOF) using WIQL Syntax
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops
- Query using Analytics
  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/analytics-récipes?view=azure-devops#retrieve-work-item-history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/analytics-r%C3%A9cipes?view=azure-devops#retrieve-work-item-history)

Comment: Actually I didn't know the CFD chart (at least haven't seen it yet). I'm just looking for an "automatic" way to show the progress of specific features (selected by a tag) and help the team leader stop creating PowerPoint presentations to show this :D. Anyway, CFD seems to almost fit what I need, except that I didn't find a way to add filters to it.

Comment: I'll check the `ASOF query` and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It seems that the entire problem can't be solved in a single query. `ASOF` is only compatible with `WIQL REST` queries and `COUNT` operations is not available on `WIQL`.